# How can i call from localhost (HTTP) an API inside website HTTPS?

Tags: laravel, http, https, cors

I'm doing some tests. I am developing an app in vue with a backend in laravel. The backend is located at an HTTPS domain that is currently online. From localhost, I would like to access the APIs located online. The main problem is CORS.

I use Laravel 9.
In App\Http\Middleware, I create Cors.php with the following code.

```
class CORS
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, 
                X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '1728000',
        ];
        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            // The client-side application can set only headers
            // allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return response()->json('OK', 200, $headers);
        }
        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }
        
        return $response;
    }
}
```

And in App\Http Kernel.php I add this.

```
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
    ];
```

The problem persists, and **`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`** is not present.

**Can I call an HTTPS API from localhost? How?**

Comment: vue tag is irrelevant, as the problem isn't specific to it

Comment: What CORS error message are you getting?

Answer (score -1):

You can add headers directly in the Nginx configuration (avoid this in production)

```
 location you-location {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;      
 }
```

Comment: what i put in "you-location"?
i add:
location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *; 
}